# Tridion Resource settings updation using /admin/refresh doesn’t work for application on multiple containers

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, sites-9

Whenever we do publish settings with updated key/value pairs in Tridion Sites 9 we have to do `/admin/refresh` to clear the cache. It works fine when application is running on single container, but when application is running on multiple containers `/admin/refresh` will not work as its going to invalidate cache from single container.

Is there anyway I can do cache clear for all the containers?

We are using DXA 2.0.5 Java with Site 9.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, DXA caches the resources (jsons and other files) on the filesystem of the webserver. By doing an `admin/refresh` you instruct the application to reload those resources from the DB. But, this is not a global operation, it only applies to that specific server. Having that in mind, the most straight forward solution is to call the `admin/refresh` on all the nodes.

If you wish, you could write custom logic to do that for you (you hit a single endpoint, then your code hits the refresh endpoint on all), or logic which would delete the specific resource files from the filesystem (which subsequently makes the framework re-save it to the file system), or some other custom solution.